# Springdoc with multi-module gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, springdoc

I'm trying to use Springdoc on a multi-module gradle project, and I'm not able to make it work.
Has someone already done something similar ?

My Gradle project structure looks like this:

My project

- Application
- module1

  - api
  - domain
  - repository
- module2

  - sames as module1

the Application module has dependencies on each module project
and
`implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: springBootVersion`

on API submodule there is:
`implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springStarterWeb` 
`implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.4.2'`

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I don't have any error on boot. The endpoints /context-path/swagger-ui.html or /context-path/v3/api-docs give 404

Comment: you need to add requestMatcher to permit swagger-ui paths

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to a sample application with multi-module project using gradle.

It contains, different kinds of configuration using gradle multi-module projects of the springdoc-openapi-ui and the springdoc-openapi-mvc-core.

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/sample-springdoc-openapi-microservices

You can see how configuration on gradle is done.